# PHP Global Variable or Best Practice

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am in the infant stages of my web development career and have a quick question.

I have a variable I am using in a lot of my controller's functions.

```
$today = new DateTime('today');
```

I have read that declaring global variables is a big no no and I would like to get away from having to declare it in each function.

What would be the best way to declare this variable and use it across all of my controllers functions?

Comment: What's the context of this variable?  I'm having difficulty imaginging what this data is for.

Comment: Can you give some more context on the controller and current usage of this variable? Is your controller in the form of a class to where you can set the value as an object property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is something you are using on your controllers only, you can just create it in a base controller:

```
<?php

BaseController extends Controller {

    protected $today;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $today = new DateTime('now');
    }

}

MyController extends BaseController {

    public function whatever()
    {
        echo "today: $this->today";
    }

}
```

If this is something you need in your views, you can use:

```
View::share('today', new DateTime('now'));
```

And it will be available to all your views:

```
Today: {{ $today }}
```

This doesn't make much sense to me, but **if you want to keep this variable between requests**, you can use the laravel Session Facade:

```
Session::put('today', now DateTime('now'));

echo Session::get('today');
```

Don't use `$_SESSION` unless you really need to take control over session handling.

Comment: The View::share method is precisely what I was looking for. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SESSION` variables to store data and still have global usage.

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['today'] = new DateTime('today');
```

Comment: Have you heard of Laravel's Session Facade? Unless you need to take control over session handling, you should not use `$_SESSION` in a Laravel application. http://laravel.com/docs/session